# Populating excel textbox form with data from listbox that shows data from access table - Error 381

Tags: excel, vba

I have a listbox in an excel form that shows only 1 field (Descripción) from an access table of 4 fields (Código, Descripción, UnidDistr, Precio). Pressing enter on the selected data in the listbox should populate the 4 fields into 4 textbox, but it only copies Code and Description fields, then it shows the error 381. Does anyone know why?

The code to fill the listbox is: (Note: It works when I use an excel table)

```
Private Sub ListBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
If KeyAscii = 13 Then
    With ListBox1
        Txt_Codigo.Value = .List(.ListIndex, 0)
        Txt_Descripción.Value = .List(.ListIndex, 1)
        Txt_Unid_Distr.Value = .List(.ListIndex, 2)     '-------> Error - 381
        Txt_Precio_Lista.Value = .List(.ListIndex, 3)
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

ListBox Properties:

```
    .ColumnCount = Rs.Fields.Count
    .ColumnWidths = "0;120;0;0"
```

Fill listbox:

```
Rs.MoveFirst
i = 0
With Form_Buscar_Productos.ListBox1
    Do
        .AddItem
        .List(i, 0) = Rs![CÓDIGO]
        .List(i, 1) = Rs![DESCRIPCIÓN]
        .List(i, 2) = Rs![UNIDDISTR]
        .List(i, 3) = Rs![PRECIO]
        i = i + 1
        Rs.MoveNext
    Loop Until Rs.EOF
End With
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you get?

Comment: How many rows and columns does your list box actually have? [Error 381 invalid property-array index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/invalid-property-array-index-error-381#:~:text=This%20error%20has%20the%20following,of%20elements%20in%20the%20array.) is caused by the access to an array element being out of bounds.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I get the error in spanish: `"error 381 en tiempo de ejecucion no se puede obtener la propiedad list. Indice de matriz de propiedades no valido"` but I guess It would be in english: `runtime error 381 unable to get list property. Invalid property matrix index`

Comment: @Samuel Everson the list box shows just ONE column "Descripción" It's the second one in the table the code I use `.ColumnWidths = "0;120;0;0"` but I load 4 columns  with `.ColumnCount = 4` so It can bring the data from fields (Código, Descripción, UnidDistr, Precio) to the 4 textboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I forgot to let you know is that when I write something in the textbox Txt_Descripción, It filter the information in the listbox, when I choose one item in the listbox it updates Txt_Descripción value, so ListIndex value also change. That's why It shows the error 381. The solution for this is to change the order I populate the textboxes, so Txt_Descripción is the last one.

```
With ListBox1
        Txt_Codigo.Value = .List(.ListIndex, 0)
        Txt_Unid_Distr.Value = .List(.ListIndex, 2)
        Txt_Precio_Lista.Value = .List(.ListIndex, 3)
        Txt_Descripción.Value = .List(.ListIndex, 1)
End With
```

That solves the problem. In this case someone else helped me with this, but Thank you anyway.